# Онлайн университет

Tags: веб-служба

Есть такой ресурс: [intuit.ru](http://www.intuit.ru/) Ищу аналоги, прошу помочь с поиском.

---

Требования к аналогам:

- Наличие русскоязычных курсов
- Прохождение тестов во время обучения
- Существование бесплатных курсов
- Должны быть курсы тематики ИТ
- Прохождение курсов онлайн

Comment: лучше intuit.ru я для себя ничего не нашёл. А что в нём не устраивает?

Comment: Там мало курсов толковых.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Это](http://hexlet.org/) Вам подойдет и язык русский и тесты есть и тематика IT.

Comment: Да, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Советую открытый универ. Это непросто, но эффективно. Все кто со мной начал завалились в первый же год(3 человека). Из восьми групп по 10-20 человек сдали в итоге только 15%. В России, если верить [Wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82_(%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), [Open University](http://www.openuniversity.edu/) и другой интересный вариант [Евразийский открытый институт](http://www.eoi.ru/) - это аналоги. Как, где, чего и сколько котируется - это уже другой вопрос. По крайней мере на информатике на сегодняшний день в открытом все курсы онлайн.

Answer (score 2):

По тематике HTML и CSS - http://htmlacademy.ru, много практики, есть много бесплатных курсов.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем по теме.
Русских online университетов, окромя Интуита - не знаю, но могу посоветовать вот такой вот интерактивный курс по Git и SVN:
http://githowto.com/ru

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](https://www.coursera.org/), конечно, нет русскоязычных материалов, однако английский довольно простой.